# Calculating area from a picture taken from a phone

Tags: python, opencv, area, defects

So basically we are working on leather image processing and we need to find area of an object using a picture in python. We have achieved an accuracy of up to 93% but we are willing to make it more accurate. **I would appreciate if the stack overflow community could help me out in a better approach to find the area of the object detected from a phone picture and it's conversion into millimeter.** 
We have already tried the reference object method but it's giving accuracy till 93%. 
Attached are sample images;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukwdZ.jpg)

Comment: I can see 1.4 rectangles in your image. How is the image related to the question and can you show your code please?

Comment: The code is confidential. However the image is useful as it is an A4 over an A2 so we can use it for conversion of pixel into millimeters.